# Python for in for loop: FileExistError

Tags: python, encryption

I am writing a program that encrypts files and decrypts them with a key. Code:

```
import random, os, time


#Collecting all files
pad = r'C:\Users\Hugo\Desktop\Malware\Test'
bestand_list = []
for files in next(os.walk(pad))[2]:
    bestand_list.append(pad + '\\' + files)



#Random 10 characters making encryption 
s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^&'
sleutel = ''
for i in range(10):
    sleutel += random.choice(s)
print(sleutel)
print('The computer is being encrypted')
time.sleep(1)


def Decrypt():
    x = 0
    decryptie = input('Enter your decryption code: \n')
    if (decryptie == sleutel):
        for bestand in bestand_list:
            for bestand_naam in bestandnaam_list:
                locatie = bestand_list[x]
                os.rename(bestand_naam, locatie)
            x += 1
        print ('Your file will now be decrypted')
    else:
        print ('Unfortunately your file was not decrypted')


def Encrypt():
    x = 0
    global bestandnaam_list
    bestandnaam_list = []
    for bestand in bestand_list:
        bestand_naam = ''
        locatie = bestand_list[x]
        for i in range (10):
            bestand_naam += random.choice(s)
        bestandnaam_list.append(pad + '\\' + bestand_naam)
        os.rename(locatie, pad + '\\' + bestand_naam)
        x += 1

    print('Your files are now encrypted')
    Decrypt()

Encrypt()
```

The problem that I am having is that the second file gets renamed to the first file by decryption. This results in a FileExistError. There is probably something wrong with the:

```
x += 1
```

in `def Decrypt()`

How to fix this issue?

Edit: Full traceback:
Traceback(most recent call last):
File "crypto.py", line 29, in Decrypt

```
os.rename(bestand_naam, locatie)
```

FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot make a file that already exists.

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations ie. which line make problem.

Comment: will edit right now

Comment: what is the aim/purpose with the renaming? How do you want that to work?

Comment: After entering the key, the filename will go back to the original. The problem is that the second file gets the same name as the first file when decrypting.

Comment: probably because you are doing all changes to your variables within the functions. Are you really sure that you change bestaand_naam_list? try with some prints to see if that is actually changed outside of your functions, which principally should work as it's own confined space in terms of variable content. In other words, you expect the variables to work like global variables, but you have not made sure that they are global..., which btw should be avoided (some say)...

Comment: you have all in message `Cannot make a file that already exists`. If you want to use the same name as other file then you have to delete it. Or you have to use `print()` to see when and why you use wrong name.

Comment: It changes, it covers all files in the folder Test and they are encrypted. @ahed87

Comment: yepp, but then you have decrypt above, is your statement still valid in decrypt... Is not the error that you are trying to rename to the same name? (and oki to the valid in decrypt)

Comment: Still valid in def decrypt. @ahed87

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had multiple problems in your code.

```
def Decrypt():
    x = 0
    decryptie = input('Enter your decryption code: \n')
    if (decryptie == sleutel):
        for bestand in bestand_list:
            os.rename(bestandnaam_list[x], bestand)
            x += 1
        print ('Your file will now be decrypted')
    else:
        print ('Unfortunately your file was not decrypted')
```

This should do the trick.

Btw when you submit your code please DO PRINT what you are doing, for you and for us and DO use english varnames since i have no clue on what sleutel and other variables names means.

You were doing 2 forloops that was giving wrong and multiples filenames/paths to os.rename .

Forgot to add this,

in `def Encrypt` you call directly Decrypt, move it to the end of the file.

Like so:

`Encrypt()
Decrypt()`

Comment: Thanks for the solution! x could be used for bestand_list and the bestandnaam_list!

Comment: I edited the code again to make it shorter, locatie is no longer declared/needed in Decrypt()